# How to superimpose two PDF/UA documents with iText5 without loosing tags?

Tags: pdf, itext, overlay, accessibility

Is there a possibility to superimpose two PDF/UA (universally accessible, tagged) documents without loosing the tags with iText5?

I have tried with the code snippet in this example for superimposing PDFs with iText5: 
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs-itext5/superimposing-content-one-pdf-another-pdf
but it seems that the tags of the documents specified in the "EXTRA" variable get lost.

Does anyone know how to manage to superimpose two PDF/UA documents without loosing the tags so that the resulting PDF is still PDF/UA compliant?

Thanks in advance,
Karin